# get value from array - google API PHP result

Tags: php, arrays, google-maps

I am trying to get the driving distance from google maps.

`print_r($result);` outputs the below:

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [elements] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [distance] => Array
                                    (
                                        [text] => 3,936 km
                                        [value] => 3935862
                                    )

                                [duration] => Array
                                    (
                                        [text] => 1 day 18 hours
                                        [value] => 150860
                                    )

                                [status] => OK
                            )

                    )

            )

    )
```

my php code to produce this is:

```
$q = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Sydney&destinations=Perth&mode=driving&sensor=false";
$json = file_get_contents($q);
$details = json_decode($json, TRUE);
$details=$details['rows'];
print_r($details);
```

I somehow need to access this array and get the distance text value, in this case `3936 km`

Any help appreciated,
Thanks as always

Comment: $result['elements'][0]['distance']['text']

Comment: Thanks Aleksandar... didnt quite work. see fiddle link on question at bottom. thanks again. output is empty.

Comment: your link is not good, it gives INVALID_REQUEST

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the question with my php that produces the error. thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$q = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Sydney&destinations=Perth&mode=driving&sensor=false";
$json = file_get_contents($q);
$details = json_decode($json, TRUE);
$details=$details['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['text'];
print_r($details);
?>
```

there you go

Answer (score 0):

If we assume that variable `$array` holds the array you have attached to your post then we can do the following:

```
echo $array['elements'][0]['distance']['text']; //should output 1300km
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, didnt quite work. see fiddle link on question at bottom. thanks again

Comment: Of course it did not worked, your $q has a syntax error. (at least the fiddle you posted).

Comment: Please use pastebin or any other simmiliar service to share your code so we can proceed in helping you!

Comment: Array you have attached to the question, is different from the one you get from the API :) just a bit see the pastebin above ^^